# Парсинг HTML страницы на Groovy

Tags: java, html, парсер, groovy

Имеется такого рода вопрос, необходимо распарсить HTML страничку на Groovy. Нагуглил сторонние библиотеки, однако проблема заключается в том, что увы мне необходимо пользоваться лишь стандартной библиотекой Groovy, а тут я уже не смог нагуглить. Возможно, кто-то с таким сталкивался. Если не сложно, подскажите каким образом это реализовать(чем воспользоваться).

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону XmlSlurper. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110181/how-to-parse-non-well-formatted-html-with-xmlslurper

Comment: Множеством способов это можно реализовать. Что именно значит "распарсить HTML" в вашем случае?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev по хорошему извлечь и проанализировать + передать на следующий этап определённые поля страницы. Но достаточно просто извлечь HTML код страницы, чтобы я имел доступ к содержимому из непосредственно кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы забрать html я воспользовался классом **URL** и методом ***getText()***.

```
def a = new URL("https://habr.com/")
String p = a.getText()
```

А уже после этого использовал регулярные выражения, чтобы найти необходимые мне данные. Решение не самое лучшее, но если ваши возможности ограничены лишь стандартной библиотекой, лучше найдено не было.